# html шаблон, вывести данные из запроса в БД

Tags: html, postgresql, golang

Покажите пожалуйста простой пример, как из запроса к базе данных, вывести результат в таблицу html шаблона.
Пишу на golang.
В веб программирование не так давно, не совсем пойму какой подход связи "запроса - таблица". В том же C++ QT мог создать модель данных и таблице просто явно указать на эту модель.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gSBQ5Brj
вот так могу вывести запрос в консоль, но не пойму как вывести его в html шаблон.

Comment: разобрался, что нужно через ResponseWriter писать
w.Write([]byte("<tr>" + bk.id + "</tr>"))
но не могу понять, что нужно в шаблоне проставить, чтобы именно в таблицу писалось.

Comment: Читайте документацию пакета [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/), тем более что там есть [примеры](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#example_).

Answer (score 0):

вот код на GO тут функция обработки запроса и парсинга в HTML файл

```
func main() {

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "dbname=.... user=.... password=.... host=... sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    database = db
    defer db.Close()

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", PageHandler)
    http.Handle("/",router)
    fmt.Println("Server is listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

type User struct {
    Name1  string
    Name2  string
}

func PageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { /
    rows, err := database.Query("select  name1, name2 from users;")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    user_current := []User{}
    for rows.Next() {
        p := User{}
        err := rows.Scan(&p.Name1, &p.Name2 )
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        user_current = append(user_current, p)
    }
    tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    tmpl.Execute(w, user_current)
}
```

а вот сам HTML файл, точнее таблица в которую из запроса попадут записи из базы

```
<div class='wrapper'>
        <table>
            <thead><th>Имя</th><th>Фамилия</th></thead>
            {{range . }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{.Name1}}</td>
                <td>{{.Name2}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{end}}
        </table>
</div>
```